# Выдает ошибку could not open input file

Tags: php, windows

Пытаюсь запустить php-шное приложение через консоль, но постоянно выдает ошибку

> could not open input file

хотя название и пути правильно написаны. С чем это может быть связано?

Comment: Какой командой вы пытаетесь запускать и что именно? Покажите хотя бы начало того файла.

Comment: Там задание запустить приложение, оно запускается командой 
php converter.php SOURCE_DIR DESTINATION_DIR
я создала папки dir 1 и dir 2
прописывала php converter.php D:\converter\dir1 D:\converter\dir2
Файл с расширением phar, но и это мне не помогло, когда я писала converter.phar
php 7.1 установлен, файл php.ini я создала и сделала так, чтобы можно было запускать через командную строку, добавив в переменные среды

Comment: Проверьте, что входной файл действительно существует. Что это за файл? Зависит от вашего приложения.

Comment: Он существует. Файл с расширением phar

Comment: Ничего не понятно! Сформулируйте ваш вопрос чётко и ясно и внесите соответствующую [правку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/704682/edit) в него, чтобы не приходилось вытягивать из вас информацию по чайной ложке. Кроме того, позаботьтесь о небольшом примере, чтобы я смог воспроизвести вашу проблему у себя на компьютере. Почитайте: [mcve], [Как эффективно сообщать об ошибках](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/bugs-ru.html).